# ajax jquery php json <select>

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

trying to populate dropdown  with local json countries list via php routing, but cant seem to make it work! It also has to take me to the selected country on the leaflet map. Can anyone please help to solve this problem? I am sure I am missing something in ajax call... many sleepless nights

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">   
       <form class="form">
           <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm text-center border-secondary font-weight-bold text-uppercase" id="selCountry">
            <option value="1">Country</option>
           </select>
        </form>
    </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);
    $result = file_get_contents("../js/countryBorders.geo.json");

    function compare($a, $b) {

        if ($a["name"] == $b["name"]) return 0;

        return ($a["name"] < $b["name"]) ? -1 : 1;

    }

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);

    $countries = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($decode['features']); $i++) {
        array_push($countries,$decode['features'][$i]['properties']);
    };

    usort($countries, "compare");
    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $countries;

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/select.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    if (result.status.name == "ok") {
          $('#selCountry').append($('<option>', {
          value: result.data.border.features[i].properties.iso_a3,
          text: result.data.border.features[i].properties.name,
        }));
      
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});
```

JSON

```
    object      {2}
type    :   FeatureCollection
    features        [175]
    0       {3}
type    :   Feature
    properties      {4}
name    :   Bahamas
iso_a2  :   BS
iso_a3  :   BHS
iso_n3  :   044
    geometry        {2}
type    :   MultiPolygon
    coordinates     [3]
```

Comment: use the browsers builtin debugger. What is being returned from the server to the browser

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'features')
    at Object.success (main.js:63:37)
    at fire (jquery-2.2.4.js:3187:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.4.js:3317:7)
    at done (jquery-2.2.4.js:8757:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.4.js:9123:9)

Comment: First thing, remove the ID from your option in the HTML. In your success you use **i** but it isn't referenced anywhere. Also, is select.php supposed to be returning the object with all countries? If so, you are looping through them anywhere.

Comment: removed ID. Added Json for more details

Answer (score 0):

A duplicate id in HTML can cause the issue, so check it if you are using it anywhere.

Comment: removed one from option, thanks